# Get last n records in Power BI from Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I created a Stream Analytics query with the input as Event Hub and output as Power BI Data Set. The stream analytics query dumps all the logs into the Data Set. As the data is continuous, the size of the dataset becomes huge and the  visualizations takes a lot of time to render.

Is there any way to retain only the latest 2000 values in the dataset to reduce visualization rendering time?

I tried using sliding window but that also does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use developer portal to purge old data in your table. http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table-rows/clear-the-rows-in-a-table?console=1